# Why Scala REPL shows tuple type for Map expression?

Tags: scala, dictionary, tuples, read-eval-print-loop

Scala REPL gives the same type for both expressions - (tuple? -- strange!). Yet `("a" ->1)` which is a Map I can add to map and `("a", 1)`can not. Why Scala REPL shows tuple type type for Map expression?

```
scala> :t ("a" -> 1)
(String, Int)

scala> :t ("a",1)
(String, Int)

scala> val m = Map.empty[String, Int]
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map()

scala> m + ("a",1)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("a")
 required: (String, ?)
          m + ("a",1)
           ^

scala> m + ("a" ->1)
res19: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the reason for this is that Predef: [http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef%24) (which is always in scope in Scala) contains an implicit conversion from Any to ArrowAssoc (the method `implicit def any2ArrowAssoc[A](x: A): ArrowAssoc[A]`)

ArrowAssoc contains the method -> which converts it to a tuple.

So basically you are doing `any2ArrowAssoc("a").->(1)` which returns ("a",1).

From repl:

```
any2ArrowAssoc("a").->(1)
res1: (java.lang.String, Int) = (a,1)
```

Furthermore, you can work on immutable hashmaps like this:

```
val x = HashMap[Int,String](1 -> "One")
x: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,String] = Map((1,One))
val y = x ++ HashMap[Int,String](2 -> "Two")
y: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map((1,One), (2,Two))
val z = x + (3 -> "Three")
z: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,String] = Map((1,One), (3,Three))
```

Answer (score 3):

Scala thinks `a + (b,c)` means you are trying to call the `+` method with two arguments, which is a real possibility since maps *do* have a multi-argument addition method so you can do things like

```
m + (("a" -> 1), ("b" -> 2))
```

the solution is simple: just add an extra set of parentheses so it's clear that `(b,c)` is in fact a tuple being passed as a single argument.

```
m + (("a", 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, I got your explanation about adding tuples! Yet another part of the question remains - about adding map to map. Do I understand write that expression `("a" -> 1 )` has a Map type? Also I could not find in Map documentation  definition of method to be used for adding maps. In fact doc has only two `+` methods both for adding tuples: `def
+(kvs: (A, B)*): Map[A, B]
[use case] Adds key/value pairs to this map, returning a new map.
abstract def
+(kv: (A, B)): Map[A, B]
[use case] Adds a key/value pair to this map, returning a new map.`

Comment: check out my answer for this :)

Comment: Rex Kerr, @Felix, thanks for your great explanations! The more I study Scala the more disappointed I am (( Looks like Scala is the language of "the most surprise" as opposed to "least surprised" ones. And the more I study Scala the more I value the beauty and clarity of Haskell !

Comment: @AntonAshanin - Languages whose quirks you know usually seem less surprising that those whose quirks you're just encountering for the first time.  I came in with different assumptions than you and didn't find the behavior surprising at all.  I agree that Haskell is a particularly elegant language, though.

Comment: Haskell is also different because it is purely functional and doesn't live on the JVM. Scala is elegant in some ways too because of its extreme flexibility in syntax.