# Why doesn't the scala compiler recognize this as a tuple?

Tags: scala

If I create a map:

```
val m = Map((4, 3))
```

And try to add a new key value pair:

```
val m_prime = m + (1, 5)
```

I get:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: (Int, ?)
       val m_prime = m + (1, 5)
```

If I do:

```
val m_prime = m + ((1, 5))
```

Or:

```
val m_prime = m + (1 -> 5)
```

Then it works. Why doesn't the compiler accept the first example?

I am using 2.10.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Scala REPL shows tuple type for Map expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602983/why-scala-repl-shows-tuple-type-for-map-expression)

Comment: see also [Appending tuple to a buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929056/appending-tuple-to-a-buffer-in-scala), it is the same underlying ambiguity between tuples and parameter lists.

Comment: @gourlaysama I think that's the opposite problem

Comment: yes, I just realized that. To be fair, it is the same compiler problem. It just messes with people in different ways :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed very annoying (I run into this frequently). First of all, the `+` method comes from a general collection trait, taking only one argument—the collection's element type. `Map`'s element type is the pair `(A, B)`. However, Scala interprets the parentheses here as method call parentheses, not a tuple constructor. The explanation is shown in the next section.

To solve this, you can either avoid tuple syntax and use the arrow association `key -> value` instead, or use double parentheses, or use method `updated` which is specific to `Map`. `updated` does the same as `+` but takes key and value as separate arguments:

```
val m_prime = m updated (1, 5)
```

---

Still it is unclear why Scala fails here, as in general infix syntax should work and not expect parentheses. It appears that this particular case is broken because of a method overloading: There is a second `+` method that takes a variable number of tuple arguments.

**Demonstration:**

```
trait Foo {
  def +(tup: (Int, Int)): Foo
}

def test1(f: Foo) = f + (1, 2)  // yes, it works!

trait Baz extends Foo {
  def +(tups: (Int, Int)*): Foo // overloaded
}

def test2(b: Baz) = b + (1, 2)  // boom. we broke it.
```

**My interpretation** is that with the vararg version added, there is now an ambiguity: Is `(a, b)` a `Tuple2` or a list of two arguments `a` and `b` (even if `a` and `b` are not of type `Tuple2`, perhaps the compiler would start looking for an implicit conversion). The only way to resolve the ambiguity is to use either of the three approaches described above.

Comment: this is a very annoying limitation. As soon as the compiler sees that `+` can be called with two parameters, it goes for it and forgets about the tuple thing. Then it doesn't type check, but it still stops there and doesn't go back to try to interpret it as a tuple. I am guessing this is because the tuple/paramlist disambiguation happens too early (during parsing, probably) for it to be able to change as a result of type checking...

Comment: Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18243932/1296806 is a more precise demonstration.  People keep asking this question.